# How do I resize the html <canvas> dynamically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, responsive-design

I was wondering how I can make my canvas resize along with my browser window? As it is right now, using innerWidth and innerHeight, it will only size to the initial browser width and height. How do I make it expand with the browser?

**Edit:** Is there a way to do this without clearing the canvas?

**JS**

```
  canvas.onmousemove = draw;
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var video = document.createElement("video");
       video.setAttribute("src", "some_video.mp4");
       video.autoplay = true;
       var img2 = new Image;
       img2.src = "some_image.png";
           ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
           ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        function draw(e){
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
           var x = e.clientX-rect.left-img2.width/2;
           var y = e.clientY-rect.top-img2.height/2;
           ctx.drawImage(video, x, y, 830, 644);
           ctx.drawImage(img2, x, y, img2.width, img2.height);
  }
```

Comment: When you change your canvas width or height properties it will clear it. If you've got a lot of complicated operations on it, making the redraw a real pain, what you can do to keep your drawings is to create an offscreen clone and then redraw it at the new size (but keep in mind it will resample the canvas content) (`var clone = canvas.cloneNode(true); clone.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0,0); canvas.width = newWidth; canvas.height = newHeight; canvas.drawImage(clone, 0,0, newWidth, newHeight);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it on `resize`

```
$(window).resize(function(){

   // Place your code here which sets the width and height of canvas.

});
```

Comment: Actually I got it to work this way, thanks! However, is there a way to do this without clearing the canvas?

Comment: Glad it worked! Consider up voting and marking it as a correct answer and resizing the can't be done without redrawing it.